# How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

Tags: python, conda, google-colaboratory

When I run:

```
from google.colab import auth
```

I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

This module is required for accessing files on Google drive from python. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can you execute the authentication code on https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=jRQ5_yMcqJiV ?

Answer (score 54):

You can simply download [google-colab](https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/) and use it in local.

```
pip install google-colab
```

Comment: I've been warned never to use pip in my conda environment as this renders conda unsupportable, not updatable, etc. Would you use this command in a conda environment?

Comment: Well, I tried it anyway in my conda shell window. It tried to download and install 11 packages, including pandas (?!) , ipython, notebook, tornado, requests and prompt_toolkit. It then failed to build wheel for pandas and declared an environmental error and unstalled about half of the packages, including tornado, google-auth and six. I suppose I should have taken the advice regarding pip: always or never, not sometimes.

Comment: WARNING: Trying this broke my environment. I don't know if it'll be the case for everyone, but I do see that the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/)'s homepage link is broken and the user is xixi who has only two projects in his name.

Comment: this broke my environment (just around 30 mins ago) as well when I was setting up my local environment when I was trying this out https://www.coursera.org/learn/advanced-computer-vision-with-tensorflow/ , had to recreate my env.

Comment: This does not seem to work outside of the Google Colab Jupyter Notebook distribution. That is why I warn everyone who is not working with Google Colaboratory to check [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621170/11154841) before you try installing this module at all.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to run google-colab from your local machine and you want to install if via conda, just type the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-colab
```

For reference: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/google-colab

Comment: for me when calling `from google.colab import drive` i get the error: `KeyError: 'CLOUDSDK_CONFIG' `. I don't think this is a complete solution.

Answer (score 9):

AFAIK, you can execute the module 'google.colab' from within the notebook environment of colab.research.google.com (it is not a publicly available package)

OFF-TOPIC:
Looking at the tag `conda` in your question. I assume that you are running the code from your local machine. Please make use of PyDrive to read from google drive on your local machine.

References:

1. [Google Colaboratory FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)
2. [PyDrive](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pydrive)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run from local machine. So this module (google.colab) cannot be installed on local machine (using pip or conda)?

Comment: You are right. 'google.colab' is part of the enviroment provided on colab.research.google.com.

Comment: But isn't the point of connecting to a local kernel from within colab that you can use the googliness of colab locally? https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html Otherwise, what's the point?  Just run jupyter locally.

Comment: The collab library is not available in the public python repository which was why the OP faced issues. Connecting to a local runtime is a feature to allow collab to utilize your hardware so that your work. Your code will still be run using the collab notebook, but the ops will be run on your local hardware

Comment: *"The colab library is not available in the public python repository."* Wow. This means the python notebook I just received which uses "from google.colab import auth" is dead on arrival, at least as far as the public python repository is concerned. As I only ever use the public repositories, I'm not aware of the private ones. How does one obtain a license to use a private repository to be able to use google.colab to import auth?

Comment: From the OP's comments I assumed they wanted to access files on google drive, also the question is from 2 years ago and a lot has changed in the colab environment. They offer a paid tier to allow your usecase @PeterLeopold, you could check it out here https://colab.research.google.com/signup