# GoogleAuth: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, google-authentication

I want to import data from google drive to a data frame. But my code breaks down at the 'from google.colab import auth' step. It says google.colab module not found.

Tried suggestions at
[How to resolve: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab/52621170)

```py
  from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
  from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
  from google.colab import auth
  auth.authenticate_user()

  import gspread
  from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

  gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())
```

**Error message:**

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code on your local machine, try using PyDrive to read from google drive to your local machine:

```
!pip install PyDrive

from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# Auto-iterate through all files that matches this query
file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'root' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()

# You can download file content using GetContentFile(filename) by initializing
# GoogleDriveFile instance with file id.

file6 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file5['id']})
file6.GetContentFile('catlove.png') # Download file as 'catlove.png'.
```

Comment: In modern Jupyter, it is now best to use the magic install command version `%pip install PyDrive`.

Answer (score -1):

That's probably because the package isn't installed. Download and install it with PIP:

`pip install google-colab`