# Cannot install Google Colab locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, windows, google-colaboratory

I have been unsucessfully trying to install google-colab on my computer (OS Windows).

The output I have when I run "pip install google-colab" is long but some of the errors that I receive are:

```
> Building wheel for pandas (setup.py) ... error   ERROR: Command
> errored out with exit status 1:    command:
> 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools,
> tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ifymdm95\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"';
> __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ifymdm95\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-02i01qsx'
```

Then after a long error output, the end is:

```
 Rolling back uninstall of pandas
  Moving to c:\users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas-1.2.0.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~andas-1.2.0.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\
   from C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~-ndas
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ifymdm95\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ifymdm95\\pandas\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-67jzzkdh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Include\pandas' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any hint or help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve this problem? I am kind of stuck with this problem.

Comment: I have this problem in python 3.8, and I couldn't find a solution. However, it installed in python 3.7 with much difficulty.

Answer (score 5):

From [Colab's issues repo](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1374#issuecomment-651203660), Craig Citro  (a software engineer on Google Colab) stated the following

> There's no way to run the colab frontend locally.

To note, however, that Colaboratory lets you connect to a local runtime using Jupyter. This allows you to execute code on your local hardware and have access to your local file system (it's a Colab frontend with a local runtime). If that is your goal, [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) you can find a way to do that.

> **Setup instructions**
>
> In order to allow Colaboratory to connect to your locally running Jupyter server, you'll need to perform the following steps.
>
> **Step 1**:
> Install Jupyter
> Install Jupyter on your local machine.
>
> **Step 2**: Install and enable the `jupyter_http_over_ws` jupyter extension (one-time)
> The `jupyter_http_over_ws` extension is authored by the Colaboratory team and available on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecolab/jupyter_http_over_ws).
>
> ```
> pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
> jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
> ```
>
> **Step 3**: Start server and authenticate
>
> New notebook servers are started normally, though you will need to set a flag to explicitly trust WebSocket connections from the Colaboratory frontend.
>
> ```
> jupyter notebook \
>   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
>   --port=8888 \
>   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
> ```
>
> Once the server has started, it will print a message with the initial
> backend URL used for authentication. Make a copy of this URL as you'll
> need to provide this in the next step. Step 4: Connect to the local
> runtime
>
> In Colaboratory, click the "Connect" button and select "Connect to
> local runtime...". Enter the URL from the previous step in the dialog
> that appears and click the "Connect" button. After this, you should
> now be connected to your local runtime.

Comment: This isn't a strictly helpful response: the guide you quote from allows you to run notebooks locally, but syncing Google Drive data still requires that you additionally install the `google-colab` library, which is what causes this error to occur

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is to run Google Colab on a local server *and* to have that local server be able to query your Google Drive just like it does in the hosted interface. The top answer resolves the first part of your question: you don't need the `google-colab` pip library to simply host locally. Having the locally hosted session work with your Google Drive is a different, more complicated matter. Referring to the answer to a similar question here:
[How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab)

I have verified that simply following the instructions from other answers does not solve the issues of making calls to the `google.drive` API in colab.

It looks like there is something wrong with installing the `google-colab` pip library inside a conda environment you intend to use to locally run colab.

I do not know what the cause is, nor how to report it, but the answer threads from the link above mentions two possible solutions to this problem:

1. Use `conda install -c conda-forge google-colab` to install `google-colab`. I know Google often says *not* to use conda-forge for its packages, and for me this gave the error `KeyError: CLOUDSDK_CONFIG`, but for others it has worked
2. Using [PyDrive2](https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2). I have not verified this, but it is an actively maintained wrapper for the Google API and has both pip and conda install hooks