# Tried to install a google-colab module. Now Anaconda Navigator will not launch, even after uninstalling, reinstalling, updating, resetting etc

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I'm using Anaconda 3.8.5 on Windows 7.

The problem: I was trying to install a Google Colab module locally, because I wanted to run [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LpEbICv1mmta7Qqic1IcRTsRsq7UKRHM#scrollTo=Nq0wA-wc-P-s) notebook on a local runtime, and it needed a module called "google-colab" (evidently this is a lost cause, as the module is not open source). I attempted to install it using `conda install -c conda-forge google-colab`, which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab?newreg=32f3de482e374d0fa4439dc0ace27dfe).

It appeared to install *something* successfully, although the notebook on colab still didn't work. After installing, Anaconda Navigator refused to launch. A command prompt popped up and disappeared instantly, and nothing else happened. I uninstalled, I reinstalled. I followed [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/43361868063/) procedure. Nothing changed at all.

When I installed Anaconda on a virtual machine with a fresh install of Windows 7 and attempted that same janky install, the exact same thing happened. Any idea how I can get Anaconda navigator back? Anaconda command prompt still works. Thank you!