# No module named 'google.colab' when connected to a local runtime in google colab

Tags: python, pip, conda, google-colaboratory

```
# This mounts your Google Drive to the Colab VM.
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# TODO: Enter the foldername in your Drive where you have saved the unzipped
# assignment folder, e.g. 'cs231n/assignments/assignment1/'
FOLDERNAME = 'cs231n/assignments/assignment1/'
assert FOLDERNAME is not None, "[!] Enter the foldername."

# Now that we've mounted your Drive, this ensures that
# the Python interpreter of the Colab VM can load
# python files from within it.
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/{}'.format(FOLDERNAME))

# This downloads the CIFAR-10 dataset to your Drive
# if it doesn't already exist.
%cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/$FOLDERNAME/cs231n/datasets/
!bash get_datasets.sh
%cd /content/drive/My\ Drive/$FOLDERNAME
```

I am trying to run this cell. When I run it from a hosted runtime it works.

However, in further cells I need more RAM so I connect to a local runtime, run the cell and get the message:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
1 # This mounts your Google Drive to the Colab VM.
----> 2 from google.colab import drive
3 drive.mount('/content/drive')
5 # TODO: Enter the foldername in your Drive where you have saved the unzipped
6 # assignment folder, e.g. 'cs231n/assignments/assignment1/'

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

Following this link:

[How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab)

I have tried:

```
pip install google-colab
```

but the installation was unsuccessful:

...
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pandas

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

I also installed conda, then installed google colab via conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge google-colab
```

but then I can't connect to a local runtime.

How do I connect to a local runtime and successfully compile the cell ?

(The question is also here: [How to resolve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab) , but I don't see the helpful answer.)