# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab' running face recognition

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm following a tutorial to make a face recognition program in python and I am getting this error:

> line 35, in 
> from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.colab'

This is my code:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2
imroot = str(input("Enter Image Path:\n"))
imroot = str("demo_img.jpg")
img = cv2.imread(imroot)
imshow(img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I tried searching on google, and found [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620788/how-to-resolve-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-google-colab), so I tried installing `google.colab.patches` locally but it tells me to install MS Visual C++. I searched on google and found out that I would have to install MS Visual Studio (not VS code), so is there and alternative for displaying images other than importing `cv2_imshow` from `google.colab.patches`?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers

Answer (score 1):

> so **is there and alternative for displaying images** other than importing
> cv2_imshow from google.colab.patches

Yes, you can either use [`Image.show`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) from [pillow](/questions/tagged/pillow) to trigger the Image Viewer of your system :

```
#pip install pillow
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("Pictures/Stack_Overflow_logo.png")

img.show()
```

Or, if you're using Jupyter Notebook, use [`IPython.display.Image`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Image) :

```
from IPython.display import Image

Image("Pictures/Stack_Overflow_logo.png")
```

[image]

Comment: OpenCV comes with it's own function to display images `cv2.imshow()`, i don't know if there was a reason why they were not using it in the tutorial, anyways add `cv2.imshow()` to your answer so i can approve it